# Why do I have brackets in my output file?

Tags: python, io

My code

```
with open('base.txt') as infile:
    r = [map(float, line.split()) for line in infile]

r1=r[::3]
r2=tuple(r1)   

with open('newindex1.txt') as infile:
    i = [map(int, line.split()) for line in infile]

a2 = zip(*i)
a11 = a2[0]
a12 = a2[1]    

with open('in.txt','w') as file:
    for index in range(len(r2)):
            file.write(str(a11[index]) + " " + str(a12[index])+ " " + str(r2[index]) + "\n")
```

Just a few lines of the output, `in.txt`:

```
0 0 [1.2]
1 0 [1.2]
2 0 [1.2]
3 0 [1.2]
4 0 [1.2]
5 0 [1.2]
6 0 [1.2]
7 0 [1.2]
8 0 [1.2]
9 0 [1.2]
```

`newindex1.txt`

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
```

`base.txt`

```
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
1.200000e+00
```

I have converted list to tuple. Why do I have brackets? How to get rid of them?

Comment: (why is `in.txt` the outfile) could you show us a bit of your input files as well?

Comment: `r` is a list of lists; converting that (or a subsection of it) to a tuple, results in a tuple of lists. That will net you (one-element) lists in your output.

Comment: It depends on what you want to iterate through? every row at a particular item, or every item in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting brackets because you are converting a list (evidently a one-element list) to a string with `str(r2[index])`.
The easiest way to fix the problem is to extract the sole element: change that to `str(r2[index][0])`.

I also recommend that you make your code less error-prone (and more readable) by replacing the too-blunt `str` operator with a string template (which, incidentally, allows you to [control the format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) of your floats, e.g. `%.2f`)

```
with open('in.txt','w') as file:
    for index in range(len(r2)):
        line = "%d %d %f\n" % (a11[index], a12[index], r2[index][0])
        file.write(line)
```

If you had done it this way and you'd accidentally forgotten the `[0]`, you would have gotten a (fairly helpful) error:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

You could also simplify your input and read `base.txt` as a simple list of floats; but since you seem to read a lot of number matrices, tbh I'd stick with your generic approach. (Apropos of that, you should look into numpy. Two-dimensional numpy arrays are just what you need for stuff like this.)

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Each index of your list `r` is a `list`. So when you set `r2` to any values in `r` here:

```
r1=r[::3]
r2=tuple(r1)
```

You're setting `r2` to be a tuple with list values. `str()` of a list will print something with brackets.